# Bridged OpenVPN Tunnel not working properly

Tags: linux, openvpn, bridge

I'm stuck with a problem:
I set up an P2P OpenVPN connection between two sites. I added the VPN TAP Interfaces into a bridge on either side.

Client side:

```
# brctl show
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
br0     8000.000db9262f8d   no      vpntap0
                                    eth1
                                    eth2
```

Server side:

```
# brctl show
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
br0     8000.000db92d05d6   no      vpntap0
                                        eth2
```

The interface eth2 on the server side is an untagged vlan connected to a dedicated server.

Now, when I add an IP Addresses to each gateway (server and client side) they can ping each other. But from the client side I cannot reach the dedicated server machine (it seems).

When I ping from the dedicated server machine I can reach the server's gateway, but not the client gateway. But the packets seem to go somewhere. When I clear the IP of the client's gateway ping complains

```
From 172.16.77.9 icmp_seq=488 Destination Host Unreachable
```

But when the client's gatway has an IP it's silent, the packet just doesn't return.

Client VPN Config:

```
remote myremotesite.tld

port 1195
proto udp
dev vpntap0
dev-type tap
secret /etc/openvpn/static.key
script-security 2
up /etc/openvpn/br-up.sh
#comp-lzo no
#cipher AES-256-CBC
```

Server VPN Config:

```
port 1195
proto udp
dev vpntap0
dev-type tap
secret /etc/openvpn/static.key
script-security 2
up /etc/openvpn/br-up.sh
#comp-lzo no
#cipher AES-256-CBC
```

Script br-up.sh (both sides):

```
#! /bin/bash

ifconfig vpntap0 promisc
ifconfig vpntap0 up 0.0.0.0
brctl addif br0 vpntap0
```

Firewall on the client side gateway is completely open.

To the firewall on the server side I added

```
iptables -I INPUT -i eth2 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -i vpntap0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -i br0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I OUTPUT -o eth2 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I OUTPUT -o vpntap0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I OUTPUT -o br0 -j ACCEPT
```

... just to make sure.

MTU is also set to 1500 on all interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, my mistake :).

I had to allow forwarding in iptables on the gateways. Thought it's not necessary for the bridge but it is...

```
iptables -I FORWARD -i br0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD -o br0 -j ACCEPT
```